# Summation of words based on two similar dataframe

Tags: r

I understand that aggregate is the way to go for the same id/words but what if they are separated in two dataframe. I have a rather complicated dataframe but I will simplify it below just to solve the core issue.

Lets say both the dataframe consist below

D1:

```
word freq  
beaten 1  
pizza 120   
test 5
```

D2:

```
word freq  
beaten 2  
pizza 65
test 3
```

How do I achieve this as below?

Result:

```
word freq    
beaten 1/(1+2)    
pizza 120/(65+120)    
test 5/(5+3)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We can use `merge` to merge the two dataframe by `word` and then divide every `freq` column of `D1` by the sum of `freq` in `D1` and `D2`.

```
df <- merge(D1, D2, by="word")
result <- data.frame(df[1], freq = df$freq.x/rowSums(df[-1]))
result

#    word      freq
#1 beaten 0.3333333
#2  pizza 0.6486486
#3   test 0.6250000
```

---

If the `word` order is same for `D1` and `D2` we can directly use

```
data.frame(D[1], freq = D1$freq/(D1$freq + D2$freq))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in a simpler way by `rbind`ing the two dataset, grouped by 'word', get the ratio of first element of 'freq' with the `sum` of 'freq'

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(D1, D2))[, .(freq= freq[1]/sum(freq)), word]
#    word      freq
#1: beaten 0.3333333
#2:  pizza 0.6486486
#3:   test 0.6250000
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(D1, D2) %>%
          group_by(word) %>%
          summarise(freq = first(freq)/sum(freq))
# A tibble: 3 × 2
#    word      freq
#    <chr>     <dbl>
#1 beaten 0.3333333
#2  pizza 0.6486486
#3   test 0.6250000
```

---

Or using `aggregate` from `base R` with similar methodology

```
aggregate(freq~word, rbind(D1, D2), function(x) x[1]/sum(x))
```